# How to remove the punctuation in the middle of a word or numbers?

Tags: python, punctuation

For example if I have a string of numbers and a list of word:

```
My_number = ("5,6!7,8")
My_word =["hel?llo","intro"]
```

Comment: `My_number` isn't a tuple, it's a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `str.translate`:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> lis = ["hel?llo","intro"]
>>> [ x.translate(None, punctuation) for x in lis]
['helllo', 'intro']
>>> strs = "5,6!7,8"
>>> strs.translate(None, punctuation)
'5678'
```

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> [ re.sub(r'[{}]+'.format(punctuation),'',x ) for x in lis]
['helllo', 'intro']
>>> re.sub(r'[{}]+'.format(punctuation),'', strs)
'5678'
```

Using a list comprehension and `str.join`:

```
>>> ["".join([c for c in x if c not in punctuation])  for x in lis]
['helllo', 'intro']
>>> "".join([c for c in strs if c not in punctuation])
'5678'
```

Function:

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
def my_strip(args):
    if isinstance(args, Iterable) and not isinstance(args, basestring):
        return [ x.translate(None, punctuation) for x in args]
    else:
        return args.translate(None, punctuation)
...     
>>> my_strip("5,6!7,8")
'5678'
>>> my_strip(["hel?llo","intro"])
['helllo', 'intro']
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant for `my_number` to be a string,

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> my_number = "5,6!7,8"
>>> my_word = ["hel?llo", "intro"]
>>> remove_punctuation = lambda s: s.translate(None, punctuation)
>>> my_number = remove_punctuation(my_number)
>>> my_word = map(remove_punctuation, my_word)
>>> my_number
'5678'
>>> my_word
['helllo', 'intro']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) + [str.isalnum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum):

```
>>> filter(str.isalnum, '5,6!7,8')
'5678'
>>> filter(str.isalnum, 'hel?llo')
'helllo'
>>> [filter(str.isalnum, word) for word in ["hel?llo","intro"]]
['helllo', 'intro']
```

This works only in python2. In python3 filter will always return an iterable and you have to do `''.join(filter(str.isalnum, the_text))`

Comment: This works only in python2. In python3 `filter` will always return an iterable and you have to do `''.join(filter(str.isalnum, the_text))`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, Thank you for advice. I included your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Unicode aware solution. `Po` is the Unicode Category for punctuation.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> mystr = "1?2,3!abc"
>>> mystr = "".join([x for x in mystr if unicodedata.category(x) != "Po"])
>>> mystr
'123abc'
```

You can do it with regex too, using the `re` module and `re.sub`. Sadly the standard library regex module doesn't support Unicode Categories, so you would've to specify all the characters you want to remove manually. There's a separate library called `regex` which has such a feature, but it is non-standard.